# 301 Redirect for Wordpress with New URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We used the Wordpress Move plugin to migrate our Wordpress site from blog.ourdomain.com to www.ourdomain.com/blog and we cannot get a 301 redirect working.  Here is our full process ...

1. Made a copy of the file folder for the wordpress site as 'blog.ourdomain.com - Copy'
2. Used the Wordpress Move plugin to change the URL from blog.ourdomain.com to www.ourdomain.com/blog.
3. Using IIS, created 'blog' as a virtual directory under ourdomain.com which pointed to the existing  'blog.ourdomain.com' folder.

... at this point, the new site was working correctly ...

4. Using IIS, pointed requests for blog.ourdomain.com to the 'blog.ourdomain.com - Copy' so that we could mess around with the htaccess and web.config folders without affecting the live site.
5. We tried several different 301 combinations in the htaccess file but nothing seems to work.  We also tries using IIS for the redirect, which did work, but we could not get it to use the dynamic URL and redirect to the correct page.

Here is an example of what we need:

OLD URL
http://blog.ourdomain.com/2017/03/orientation-packages-for-new-employees/

Needs a 301 redirect to:
http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/2017/03/orientation-packages-for-new-employees/

Perhaps the sub-directory is the part that is messing us up but we're not having any success using htaccess at all, not even redirects to the wrong URL.  The only thing that made any changes was using IIS for the redirects which will only redirect: 
http://blog.ourdomain.com/2017/03/orientation-packages-for-new-employees/
to:
http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/

Please help.  What else should we try?  What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the advice.  What ended up working was using specific redirects in the web.config file.  Our biggest issue here was not understanding that the htaccess file is only used by Apache.  We have Windows server with IIS7 which uses the web.config file.  Below are some examples of what we added.  Please understand that this worked for us because of the URL formatting used with our Wordpress installation.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect - Category - Paging">
          <match url="^category/([_0-9a-z-] )/page/([0-9] )/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/category/{R:1}/page/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - Category">
          <match url="^category/([_0-9a-z-] )/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/category/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - Author">
          <match url="^author/([_0-9a-z-] )/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/author/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - Individual Blog">
          <match url="^([0-9] )/([0-9] )/([_0-9a-z-] )/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - Month Archive">
          <match url="^([0-9] )/([0-9] )/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/{R:1}/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - About Us">
          <match url="^about-us/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/about-us" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - Privacy">
          <match url="^privacy/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/privacy" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - Home Page - Paging">
          <match url="^page/([0-9] )/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/page/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect - Home Page">
          <match url="^" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ourdomain.com/blog" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```